# PHP Namespace Class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, namespaces, extend

I read up quite a bit on namespaces in PHP and I'm still confused.

I have a class in a different folder that is under the namespace Entity (Class A).

I have another class in a different folder that is under the same namespace (Class B), and extends class A.

I get an error saying class A could not be found.

My main question is - do I have to include class A when I create a new instance of class B?

This is my code:
(Class A)

```
 namespace Entity;
    //Framework/Entity/BaseModel.php
    class BaseModel { 

      //TODO: IMPLEMENT THIS
      public function GetList() {
        return null;
      }

    }
```

(Class B)

```
namespace Entity;
//Models/Points.php
class Points extends BaseModel{
    public $Id = null;
}
```

(Main File)

```
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/Models/Points.php');
  $points = new Points();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces have nothing to do with actually including files, those are two completely separate mechanisms. So, yes, you will still have to `require_once` the file that the class is defined in before you can use it.

Having said that, especially with namespaces, autoloaders are typically used so you don't have to write a ton of `require` code. If you organise your class files in folders exactly as their namespaces are, it's very easy to autoload their files. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php and https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Answer (score 0):

Parent class definition must be know on definition of child class. 
Even before you create instance of child class.

How otherwise PHP would know what to put inside class you create?

```
require_once('BaseModel.php')
namespace Entity;
//Models/Points.php
class Points extends BaseModel{
    public $Id = null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, including the parent before the child.

Comment: You import class when you include file containing definition. `include`, `require`, `require_once` - pick one. Sample in answer. Or learn how to use autoloaders (IMHO better solution).